# How to dynamically change the text index in mongodb for a single collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, full-text-search, eve

Is it possible to change the text index search dynamically on a single collection on mongodb? I originally have a `$text` index on the `first.text` field of my collection, but when the user presses a button, I want to switch over to only allow the text search to be done on the `second.text` field. I am aware that only one text index can be created on a mongodb collection at a time.

Here is an example of what my collection schema looks like for simplicity, I just want to get feedback on if it's possible to change dynamically without giving up any cost for performance:

```
{
    first : {
        text : 'search here'
    },
    second : {
        text : 'search ONLY here after a button press'
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make `on_pre_GET` hook and use `ensureIndex(...)` to make your index or drop index using `dropIndexes(...)`

but manipulating indexes is a major action and it has huge cost on performance. mongoDb says:

> By default, creating an index blocks all other operations on a database. When building an index on a collection, the database that holds the collection is unavailable for read or write operations until the index build completes

you can make REGULAR index on each field and use $regex like:

`?where={"first.text": {"$regex": ".*search.*"}}`